# mysql order by custom field with and list also these fields which are missing in custom list

Tags: mysql

I would like to make a query for mysql:

```
select field1, count(*) as c
from temporary table
group by field1
order by field(field1, 'XXX', 'YYY', 'ZZZ')
```

so this makes a nice group i.e.:

```
XXX  ZZZ

454  321
```

But, if there isn't any YYY values, because count(*) for YYY "returns 0", this is not listed like the XXX and ZZZ and should not be skipped because empty (or null) fields.

but I would like this output:

```
XXX  YYY  ZZZ

454    0  321
```

is that possible only in mysql?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Edited! If I do this query from causal table (not temporary) it works! but why not from temporary??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use SELECT * but the list of your fields SELECT fields, fields1, fields2
If your result is NULL or 0 you will have your column

Comment: yes it works, thanks, but, I've forgotten, that I use temporary tables for this query (select field1 from temporary table), and if you select it from temporary it does not work, do you know why? if you select from normal table, it works.

Comment: Sorry, if there is a where clause, it is also not working... :/ :( why??

Comment: What's your request to create your temporary table ?

Comment: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS (SELECT * from table3 where field !='')  so i don't think it depends on it, because, if you put a where clause in the normal query (try to use a causal table) then it is also not working. If you remove the where clause, it works like you sad...

Comment: When you create your table do you have data from YYY ?

Comment: I think that when you create your temporary table if the datas of the table that you copy are empty, they are not created (to check) what the problem of "where clause" since you ask him for datas that he does not know. Can you check that?

Comment: Yes, I know, he does not know, but, thats why I added it to the custom list, which it should be listed. The where clause seems to be the problem.